# Irrelevant close flags taking value away from the community

Tags: support, close-reasons

Today I asked the community for some recommendations on a **product carousel** extension.

[Product Carousel Extension Recommendation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36635/product-carousel-extension-recommendation)

I also got the answer which I was looking for.

The question was flagged to be closed, and so far here are the votes:

**too broad - 3**

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

**primarily opinion-based - 1**

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert
>   experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific
>   expertise.

I don't see how the question falls into any of those topics (too broad? I've asked simply for a product carousel extension - and primarily opinion based? What the heck?)

In any case, I feel like people are too hastily flagging questions to be closed (who knows why, maybe to up the sites' Q:A ratio).

Would appreciate some insight into this, hasty flagging is going to take value away from the community.

Answer (score 4):

the problem on this kind of question is, there are a lot more then 10 possible carousels. Maybe even above 100.

All very different, so in the end its only personal opinion, what everyone is suggesting.

also, a simple google search should bring up a lot of possible solutions. Or a magento connect search.